# Hard Coding values in mule data mapper

Tags: xml, mule

How Can I hard code values in the mule data mapper. I need to set xml attributes values for instance my xml:

```
<InvestProductTypeCode tc="9">Unit Trust</InvestProductTypeCode>
```

Mule data mapper then gives you two attributes to edit for InvestProductTypeCode namely:

tc:integer (the attribute i need to hardcode to 9)

text(): String (the value of InvestProductTypeCode which is mapped from a json file)

how can i hardCode the tc attribute. or is there another way to set xml attributes in data mapper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this via the 'script' editor rather than the 'graphical' tab.

And then something like:

```
output.tc = '9';
```

Or alternatively it maybe better to store this value in a 'lookup table' as a constant. More on lookup tables here: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Using+DataMapper+Lookup+Tables